# On 404 do not go anywhere (PHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, errordocument

I am creating an application in PHP.
One thing I want to do is make it so that if a user types in www.example.com/app/rrr.php where app is the main directory of my application and rrr.php does not exist, that either the program does not go anywhere or use ErrorDocuments in .htaccess to redirect back to the previous page. Thus far the only way I have been able to get this is to add this in my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\wamp\www\Master\errorcode.php
```

When I try to go to a page that does not exist (by typing in the address area), the program does not attempt to go to it. On a page that does exist (if I type in a php file that I have made) the program advances normally. My problem is that I doubt this will work for users who install it themselves, and I was wondering if anyone had ideas as to how to make this work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Couln't understand your question fully, but what I think is,

You should direct user to 404 page where you will check if there is any referer then give a link along with 404 page something like `You might want to go back`, and if there is no referer just show 404 page.

Comment: The way it works right now is if I have that line in my .htaccess, if people type into the browserbar a link that does not exist, then the page treats it like nothing ever happened. I'd like to keep it like that but if I distribute the app with the .htaccess line above, I'm not sure if its going to work or not.

Comment: Yes, it should work as far as it's apache. Or you can provide additional README file where you ask user to do this edit before actually using it.